# Solve limit without L'Hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'd like some help in solving this limit without using L'Hopital -

$$ \lim_{x\to 1}
\left(
\frac3{1-x^{1/2}} -
\frac2{1-x^{1/3}}
\right)
$$

([Original formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6t0z.png))

Comment: Welcome to Math SE, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome Yuri: each summand tends to $\pm\infty$ when $x$ tends to $1$ so the limit should not exist, I believe, because it is not well defined for both sides the same limit, i.e are distinct to the left and to the right

Comment: @Ataulfo There **is** a limit -- see the two answers below.

Comment: @Clement C. Well, errare humanum est.....Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a (somewhat long, but detailed) solution, using the systematic approach of [Taylor expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions).
It relies on the following series expansion to second order on a neighborhood of $0$:
$$
(1+h)^\alpha = 1+\alpha h + \frac{\alpha(\alpha-1)}{2}h^2 + o(h^2)
$$
when $h\to0$, for any fixed $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. (Applied below 3 times; with $\alpha=1/2$, $\alpha=1/3$, and $\alpha=-1$, after the change of variable $x=1+h$ (so that $h\to 0$)).

---

Write $x=1+h$, where $h\to0$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
\frac3{1-x^{1/2}} -
\frac2{1-x^{1/3}}
&= 
\frac3{1-(1+h)^{1/2}} -
\frac2{1-(1+h)^{1/3}} \\
&= 
\frac3{1-(1+\frac{h}{2}-\frac{h^2}{8}+o(h^2))} -
\frac2{1-(1+\frac{h}{3}-\frac{h^2}{9}+o(h^2))}\\
&= 
\frac{-6}{h-\frac{h^2}{4}+o(h^2)} +
\frac{6}{h-\frac{h^2}{3}+o(h^2)} \\
&=
\frac{6}{h}\left(\frac{-1}{1-\frac{h}{4}+o(h)} +
\frac{1}{1-\frac{h}{3}+o(h)} \right) \\
&=
\frac{6}{h}\left(-(1+\frac{h}{4}+o(h)) +
(1+\frac{h}{3}+o(h)) \right) \\
&=
\frac{6}{h}\left(\frac{h}{3}-\frac{h}{4}+o(h)) \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} + o(1).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Note that this is *not* the fastest nor the most elegant method. Just one that works in 99.9% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{3}{1-x^{\frac{1}{2}}}-\frac{2}{1-x^{\frac{1}{3}}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{3}{1-\sqrt{x}}-\frac{2}{1-\sqrt[3]{x}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{1+2\sqrt[6]{x}}{1+2\sqrt[6]{x}+2\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt{x}}=$$
$$\frac{1+2\sqrt[6]{1}}{1+2\sqrt[6]{1}+2\sqrt[3]{1}+\sqrt{1}}=\frac{1+2\cdot 1}{1+2\cdot 1+2\cdot 1}=\frac{1+2}{1+2+2+1}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

To facilitate the analysis, we note that be making a substitution $x\to x^6$, the limit is equivalent to

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{3}{1-x^3}-\frac{2}{1-x^2}\right)&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{3}{(1-x)(1+x+x^2)}-\frac{2}{(1-x)(1+x)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1+x-2x^2}{(1-x)(1+x)(1+x+x^2)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{(1-x)(1+2x)}{(1-x)(1+x)(1+x+x^2)}\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{(1+2x)}{(1+x)(1+x+x^2)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12
\end{align}$$